# After adding a video tag by js - events doesn't work (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have this video player code (simplistically)

```
<div class="videoPlayer">
  <video width="300" height="200">
    <source src="480p.mp4">
  </video>
  <div>...myControls...</div>
</div>
```

And by this jQuery code I take its events.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('video').on('canplay',function(){...});
  $('video').on('timeupdate',function(){...});
  $('video').on('progress',function(){...});
  $('video').on('ended',function(){...});
});
```

Аnd it works.
But when I want to add HTML code with jQuery, the following way.

HTML

```html
<div class="myVideo" data-src="video/480p.mp4"></div>
```

JS

```js
if($(".videoPlayer").length>0){
  $('.videoPlayer').each(function(){
      var th=$(this),
      vidSrc=th.attr('data-src'),
      playerHTML='<div class="videoPlayer videoPlayerNew"><video width="300" height="200"><source src='+vidSrc+'></video><div>...myControls...</div></div>';
      th.replaceWith(playerHTML);
      $(".videoPlayerNew").find("video").load();
      $(".videoPlayerNew").removeClass("videoBlockNew");
  });
}
```

**canplay**, **timeupdate**, **progress** and **ended** events no work.

The remaining properties remain working (play, stop, ...).

*How can I get these events (canplay, timeupdate, progress, ended).*

Comment: Try  [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) .. for simplicity `$(document).on('canplay', 'video' ,function(){...});`

Comment: In doing so, even the first method becomes non-working